# CloudAdapterException - Oracle SOA - ERP Cloud Adapter

Tags: oracle-soa

Getting the error -

*oracle.fabric.common.FabricInvocationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/tip/tools/adapters/cloud/api/CloudAdapterException*

in Oracle Soa 12.2.1.4.0 while using Oracle ERP Cloud adapter with operation-submitESSJobRequest.
Selected ErpIntegrationService as service.